# C++ Copying a Const Referenced Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, linked-list, operator-overloading

We're having trouble passing a pointer reference as a constant, copying the referenced pointer to a non-constant, and sending it to a class function.

This problem has a simple fix: allow the passed parameter to be passed as a non-constant. Unfortunately, this is for a project and the header file must remain unchanged. Here's the basic idea:

- There exists a universe of points; each point is a structure instance that contains dimension and values.
- There also exist clusters of addresses to points; clusters do not contain instances of the points themselves, but just their location. This allows for overlap in the "contents" of a cluster without duplication of physical data. All points in a cluster are organized by link list; the cluster itself points to the first node, and each node points to the subsequent node until null.

Thus:

```
class Point
{
    int dim;          // number of dimensions of the point
    double *values;   // values of the point's dimensions
}
```

and:

```
typedef Point * PointPtr;          // Points to a point
typedef struct LNode * LNodePtr;   // Points to a link node

struct LNode         // Link node structure
{
    PointPtr p;      // Points to a point
    LNodePtr next;   // Points to the next link node
};

class Cluster
{
    int size;
    LNodePtr points;

public:
    Cluster &operator+=(const Point &rhs);   // Add a point
}
```

We are required to overload the += operator to add a point to a cluster, and were given the above declaration. So far, the only code that somewhat behaves is the following:

```
Cluster &Cluster::operator+=(const Point &rhs)   // This line is not allowed to change
{
    PointPtr newPtPtr = new Point(rhs);
    this->add(newPtPtr);   // Adds the point to the cluster
    return *this;
}
```

But, this creates a new physical point in the universe.

What we'd like to see work is something along the lines of the following:

```
Cluster &Cluster::operator+=(const Point &rhs)
{
    PointPtr newPt = &rhs;   // This could also be type "Point *"
    this->add(newPt);
    return *this;
}
```

But I'm receiving an "invalid conversion" message:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const Clustering::Point*' to 'Clustering::PointPtr {aka Clustering::Point*}' [-fpermissive]
     PointPtr newPt = &rhs;
```

All I can see that is different is the constant - is there any workaround to capture that referenced pointer address?

Comment: Why does `add` need to take a non-`const` pointer, or a pointer at all?

Comment: How is `add()` defined?

Comment: add() creates a new link node and lexicographically sorts its address into the cluster. I didn't include it, since it's a wall of (working) code that appears to be outside the scope of this. The error occurs at &[here]rhs in the "ideal" code above.

Comment: Note: your first attempt leaks memory.

Comment: @Miller The implementation of `add` isn't necessary but the function signature sure is important to answering your question. Also, you really should be providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Miller Why does `add` need to take a non-`const` pointer, or a pointer at all?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It would have undefined behavior if anything later actually attempts to modify the `Point`, but I think you could write

```
Cluster &Cluster::operator+=(const Point &rhs)
{
    PointPtr newPt = const_cast<PointPtr>(&rhs);
    this->add(newPt);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: A const_cast and an easy way to get a UB because of binding of a temp to a const ref? No thanks. There are a lot of problems with OP's code but your advice is just asking for even more troubles.

Comment: @Rostislav I'm not in any way suggesting that it is good programming practice, but it is a way to get around the restrictions of the header file.  If there is no reason that the point will be modified through the cluster, the cluster ought to use const pointers, but I am assuming that the Cluster is also part of the header file and cannot be changed.

Comment: @Miller If you use this, expect to run into odd problems at some point.

Comment: It is unlikely to be used beyond this assignment.

Comment: @Rostislav - I agree it's not good coding practice. This will never see industry.